# Defining multicolum by macro with optional argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, multline

I try to define macro for shortcut form `\multiline{1}{<pcolumn type>}{\textbf{text}}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,preview]{standalone}

\newcommand\mcbf[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
    \hline
\mcbf{|c|}{AAA}  &   \mcbf{c|}{BBB}   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Which work as expected. Since in the most a case I use the same column specifier i try to redefine this macro so, that the default column type is for example `c|`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,preview]{standalone}

\newcommand\xmcbf[2][c|]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\xmcbf[|c|]{AAA} &   \mcbf{BBB}  \\ \hline
C                &   D           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Which gives error:

```
\multispan ->\omit
                  \@multispan
```

What I miss in `\newcommand` definition? My (probably clumsy) search in SE doesn't gives useful information.

Comment: I assume `\mcbf` is a typo for `\xmcbf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the command to *expand* to `\multicolumn`

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=1mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\xmcbf{O{c|}m}{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\xmcbf[|c|]{AAA} &   \xmcbf{BBB}  \\ \hline
C                &   D           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCalise, thank you. This is over my knowledge of LaTeX ... but now I have solution :-)

Comment: @DavidCalise,usually, when I stuck in LaTeX I look in `LaTeX Companion` (I owned second, printed edition). It is inestimable
source, when I need insight to some rare used package or looking for solutions which provides packages for which I'm not aware. I wonder, if we  can expected its third edition which will incorporate between other `xparse` package?

Comment: @Zarko perhaps, one day....

Comment: @Zarko IMHO, TeXbook is an "inestimable source". The answer to your problem can be found here: `\omit` or `\span` must be first primitive command(s) after full expansion and space ignoring in data area in `\halign`. It means that your problem isn't typically LaTeX problem but it is TeX problem. And I doubt that such answer can be found in LaTeX documentation.

Comment: @wipet but that answer doesn't really help as knowing that doesn't tell you how to define parsing for an optional `[]` argument in an expandable way, which is the point of the question, and the point of `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`