# How to put braces over certain parts of matrices?

Tags: matrices, arrays, braces, blkarray

I want to typeset something like this:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to achieve this using `array` or `blkarray`. Any help?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407979/1090

Comment: `overbrace` ist your friend, I think.

Comment: @TiMauzi I couldn't bring it to put brace over different columns of matrices.

Comment: @Atom How about you just put the overbrace on top of the topmost row's values in your matrix? Meaning, you just put the overbrace IN the `array`, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `nicematrix` package. Note that **you must compile twice** to get the result.

Note also that `\OverBrace` is a relatively new addition to `nicematrix`, so if you're using an old installation you'll have to update.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
m\begin{BNiceArray}{cccc|cc}[right-margin=.4em]
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix[{1-3}{2-6}]
\OverBrace[shorten,yshift=3pt]{1-1}{2-2}{n}
\OverBrace[shorten,yshift=3pt]{1-3}{2-4}{r}
\OverBrace[shorten,yshift=3pt]{1-5}{2-6}{s}
\end{BNiceArray}n
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that seems to be one impressively thoughtful package. The more you know...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this is what you are looking for:

```
\begin{array}{c}
  & n & & r & & s & \\
  m\,\big\lbrace & \overbrace{A} & \big[ & \overbrace{P} & \big\vert & \overbrace{Q} & \big] & \big\rbrace\,n
\end{array}
```

[image]

I think it could be made prettier (e.g. fixing some space widths and resizing the variables), but I think the overall idea should be clear.

Comment: That's a nice possibility!

Comment: @Atom If you prefer all the `\overbrace`s to have the same height, just put them in an own row of your `array` and leave the braces empty.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/label-rows-of-a-matrix-by-characters