# Vertical space before and after hrule in tabular tables

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

Consider this example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \downbracefill\\\hline
  text\\\hline
  \upbracefill
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In the produced document, the vertical spacing between `downbracefill` and the first `hline` is not the same as the one between the second `hline` and `upbracefill`.  This can also be reproduced with `\hrulefill` instead of `\downbracefill` and `\upbracefill`.

I suppose this has to do with the placement of the baselines.

How can I control the vertical space before and after `hrule` to make them equal in situations like in the given example?

Comment: Is using something like `$\overbrace{\underbrace{\text{text text text}}}$`  sufficient for you? (if not why?)

Comment: @user202729, i wish to put overbraces and underbraces over and under different spans of cells in a table.

Comment: Weird workaround: Add `\\[-16.8pt]` after the second `\hline`. Credit partially https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84524/how-to-make-a-row-in-a-table-shorter

Comment: Use to raise the lower cell use `\raisebox{3.6pt}{\upbracefill} `.  To calculate the raise, well ....

Answer (score 3):

The up/down-bracefill is only a component (it consists from three sub-components but it is not important now) used in the plain TeX macro `\overbrace`, `\underbrace`. This macro adds it over/under the given text without any vertical skips, the result is box over box. So, there is not important, how the up/down-bracefill is vertically positioned in respect to a general strut or to parentheses. The vertical position of these components chosen by D. Knuth is somewhat lower than you need. You can try to typeset:

```
(\downbracefill), (\upbracefill)
```

and you will see. D. Knuth didn't need to solve vertical position more accurately and we can only guess why the position was chosen as it was.

**Edit:** If you want to have horizontally stretchable `\upbracefill` and moreover to have vertical rules in the table, then you can try to apply affine transformation (shifting) before `\upbracefill` and then apply the inverse transformation:

```
\def\upbracecorr{3.5 }
\def\xupbracefill{\pdfliteral{1 0 0 1 0  \upbracecorr cm}%
   \upbracefill   \pdfliteral{1 0 0 1 0 -\upbracecorr cm}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
  \downbracefill\\\hline
  text text text\\\hline
  \xupbracefill
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: So, how do you suggest me to get small and equal vertical spacing in the indicated places?

Comment: @Alexey If you don't want to have `\upbracefill` horizontally stretchable then you can write `\raise.8ex\hbox{\upbracefill}` instead `\upbracefill` in your example. If you want to have `\upbracefill` stretchable and moreover, you want to keep the horizontal lines in the table, then the problem is more complicated. Give more specification of your needs.

Comment: I added a solution of shifting `\upbracefill` to my answer. Use pdftex, where `\pdfliteral` is implemented. If you are using LuaTeX then define `\protected\def \pdfliteral        {\pdfextension literal}`.